# How to make scatterplot points open a hyperlink using ggplotly - R

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, htmlwidgets, ggplotly

I'd like to make my scatterplot points clickable and have each point's respective hyperlink open when clicked. I am trying to do this using ggplotly.
There is a simple way to do this when building the plot using plotly()(see first example below). However, when running it on ggplotly, an empty webpage opens when I click.

Anyone know how I can make this work with the code below? Could there be a solution on the OnRender portion of the code (not familiar with javascript)?
The first code chunk using plotly works. The second code chunk is my basic attempt at thisusing ggplotly, which does not work.

Any guidance on this would be amazing! thanks in advance

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$url <- paste0("http://google.com/search?q=", gsub(" ", "+", rownames(mtcars)))

#1. Using plotly
p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_markers(customdata = ~url)
onRender(p, "
         function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
         var url = d.points[0].customdata;
         window.open(url);
         });
         }
         ")

#2. Using ggplotly`
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg))+
  geom_point()
pp <- ggplotly(p)
pp  <- add_markers(pp, customdata = ~url)
onRender(pp, "
         function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
         var url = d.points[0].customdata;
         url
         window.open(url);
         });
         }
         ")
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://plotly-r.com/supplying-custom-data.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `add_markers(pp, customdata = ~url)` has no effect. That works by doing:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
pp <- ggplotly(p)
pp$x$data[[1]]$customdata <- mtcars$url
#pp  <- add_markers(pp, customdata = ~url)
ppp <- onRender(pp, "
         function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
         var url = d.points[0].customdata;
         //url
         window.open(url);
         });
         }
         ")
```

Comment: Thank you for this. its definitely works thanks a lot. However, do you know if the click gets disables when you change the shape of the point or input annotations to the plot. Ultimately my plot is presented on Shiny dashboard and my scatter points are of different geometric shape and my plot has rectangle annotations. Code would look something like this

Comment: `p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate('rect', xmin = 2, xmax = 6, ymin = 2, ymax = 6, fill="firebrick", alpha = .2)
  
pp <- ggplotly(p)
pp
pp$x$data[[1]]$customdata <- mtcars$url
#pp  <- add_markers(pp, customdata = ~url)
ppp <- onRender(pp, "
                function(el, x) {
                el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
                var url = d.points[0].customdata;
                //url
                window.open(url);
                });
                }
                ")
ppp`

Comment: be careful, this is not working if you use colors, groups, facets etc...

Answer (score 5):

This is a more generic version of Stéphane's solution, which is not working when using groups, colors, facets etc. Everything is fine if you specify your urls directly in the *customdata* aesthetic:

```
mtcars$url <- paste0("http://google.com/search?q=", gsub(" ", "+", rownames(mtcars)))

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = as.character(carb), customdata = url)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~cyl)
pp <- ggplotly(p)
ppp <- htmlwidgets::onRender(pp, "
     function(el, x) {
     el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
     var url = d.points[0].customdata;
     //url
     window.open(url);
     });
     }
     ")
```